# C# WPF Dependency Property not be notified for all subproperty data binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

Here is my code, I am writing a simple `WPF` application with Dependency property, I fail in the data binding for those sub property, but works in those normal property such as string, int. Any idea?

```
<!-- Work -->
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding address}"/>
<!-- Not work -->
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding child.Name}"/>


public class Child
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public Child child
{
    get { return (Child)GetValue(childProperty); }
    set { SetValue(childProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty childProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("child", typeof(Child), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));


public String address
{
    get { return (String)GetValue(addressProperty); }
    set { SetValue(addressProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty addressProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("address", typeof(String), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Comment: There is no change notification for the Name property in class Child. The class should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and fire the PropertyChanged event in the setter of the Name property. As a note, `new PropertyMetadata(null)` is redundant, and you should use consistent naming conventions for all your properties, e.g. `public Child Child` and `public string Address`.

Comment: Thanks Clemens. Yes, it works when the Child implements the INotifyPropertyChanged.